# Controller print_r shows different from model print_r

Tags: php, model-view-controller

This is following up question [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081290/how-to-pull-out-data-from-nested-array-in-php). But the question is different.

I have the following model and print_r is the following as well.

```
This is Model MCalendar_one/getEvents($time)

function getEvents($time){ 
...   
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eventDate,'%d') AS
 day,eventContent,eventTitle FROM eventcal WHERE eventDate BETWEEN 
'$current_year/$current_month/01' AND 
'$current_year/$current_month/$total_days_of_current_month'");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row_event)
{                   
$events = $row_event;
echo "<pre>";
 print_r ($events);
echo"</pre>";
        }

Print_r is this.
Array
(
    [day] => 17
    [eventContent] => event 1 of 17th
    [eventTitle] => 17th event 1
)

Array
(
    [day] => 19
    [eventContent] => event 1 of 19th
    [eventTitle] => 19th event 1
)

Array
(
    [day] => 05
    [eventContent] => event 1 of 5th
    [eventTitle] => 5th event 1
)

Array
(
    [day] => 17
    [eventContent] => event 2 of 17th
    [eventTitle] => 17th event 2
)

Array
(
    [day] => 19
    [eventContent] => event 2 of 19th
    [eventTitle] => 19th event 2
)

Array
(
    [day] => 19
    [eventContent] => event 3 of 19th
    [eventTitle] => 19th event 3
)

Array
(
    [day] => 25
    [eventContent] => birthday
    [eventTitle] => birthday
)
```

Now I add the following in a controller and print_r() as well. But the outcome is different. It displays only the last one.

Could anyone tell me how to dispaly all of the array plz?

Thanks in advance.

```
This is in Controller
$data['events']=$this->MCalendar_one->getEvents($time);

In view
print_r $events;

this displays 
Array ( [day] => 25 [eventContent] => birthday [eventTitle] => birthday )
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
$events = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row_event) {                   
  // append $row_event to $events;
  $events[] = $row_event;
}
echo "<pre>events: ";
print_r($events);
echo"</pre>";
return $events;
```

or even simpler

```
return $query->result_array();
```